# I can't access docker container from the web

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-machine

I have created a docker container for a `Laravel` application. When I try to access it from the web I get some html page that says "It works". I was not able to find that HTML file inside of ot the docker container even when I logged in as root. I have mounted the apache configuration file with a `apache2.conf` file in my project. I will post some code below with configuration because I'm already out of ideas.

Docker container after runned `docker inspecct webserver`

```
    {
    "Id": "e0a6f58269ebdfb67afcebbac397727d065dda5a7159cd63e296f7ca0bf18552",
    "Created": "2020-02-07T08:37:24.701014739Z",
    "Path": "/entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "/run.sh"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 13842,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2020-02-07T08:44:04.129079753Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2020-02-07T08:43:54.29560322Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:2917481c38ded1d217cf1498a3ebc7378916ce7d9a06e06377e7c296fd80827e",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e0a6f58269ebdfb67afcebbac397727d065dda5a7159cd63e296f7ca0bf18552/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e0a6f58269ebdfb67afcebbac397727d065dda5a7159cd63e296f7ca0bf18552/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e0a6f58269ebdfb67afcebbac397727d065dda5a7159cd63e296f7ca0bf18552/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e0a6f58269ebdfb67afcebbac397727d065dda5a7159cd63e296f7ca0bf18552/e0a6f58269ebdfb67afcebbac397727d065dda5a7159cd63e296f7ca0bf18552-json.log",
    "Name": "/webserver",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
    "ExecIDs": [
        "3f34da41b52416c84ba6a9a88d38b75f65715fa1b3766cfb545fb4fef6871fdb"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/home/chris/Public/Projects/admin-website/docker/apache2/default.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:rw",
            "/home/chris/Public/Projects/website:/var/www/admin-website:rw"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "website_app-network",
        "PortBindings": {
            "443/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "443"
                }
            ],
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "unless-stopped",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": [],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Capabilities": null,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "shareable",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a45b15f7a18a3a7ea624dbf14e3f723426611ba75f64a8e10d7b7e4c33dd4d79-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/005275602d2c99dd75b65bd10a71e264d0c5c73d5b1e4e5127c7f74335184d58/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5af8337dbc6e47fe9843bce35777aeadaa49253f4d75b0827c9571640ea2289b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2c55f1c77761d6ae27778ee70e33606da0b04f52a24e3c9a70819a243216d68e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0090ca1d47c0f281c8abfd98863e8a6a7896be449b03771c5f3ac1fe10d8d5ae/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2a83e2e784cb5fb3b852da312c89ad4abf6f42e3408e1bf236ecf9a564f371d4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c6a2488ca71dcb2279909dd24b781b5ee8a0fd80bead495e5b5851c0f4efbc62/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1a4fdba6c32cf797cd820f82e95f3d0eed837b1c8103458317c10450f57714f9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e0dca46d5ad13ceea4274955428e94b82abc037907da0e57a633e9ebc183b74e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0453a3d8c5d31dd4481ab1f2dd670a96a7f1e0c5c39b429d0123d26b69dc6998/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/291d9e57dae6eefd324d21a6bf593f4a3e244cc44c3a83101b37d57f5dc24e4c/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a45b15f7a18a3a7ea624dbf14e3f723426611ba75f64a8e10d7b7e4c33dd4d79/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a45b15f7a18a3a7ea624dbf14e3f723426611ba75f64a8e10d7b7e4c33dd4d79/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a45b15f7a18a3a7ea624dbf14e3f723426611ba75f64a8e10d7b7e4c33dd4d79/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/chris/Public/Projects/admin-webiste/docker/apache2/default.conf",
            "Destination": "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/chris/Public/Projects/website",
            "Destination": "/var/www/website",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "e0a6f58269eb",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "1001",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "443/tcp": {},
            "8080/tcp": {},
            "8443/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/opt/bitnami/apache/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "HOME=/",
            "OS_ARCH=amd64",
            "OS_FLAVOUR=debian-10",
            "OS_NAME=linux",
            "BITNAMI_APP_NAME=apache",
            "BITNAMI_IMAGE_VERSION=2.4.41-debian-10-r11"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/run.sh"
        ],
        "Image": "bitnami/apache:latest",
        "Volumes": {
            "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf": {},
            "/var/www/website": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "/app",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "adc335a950efdb40fd9f77c9b13183c105f335558bdf520a53efc5a766da703d",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "website",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "webserver",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.21.2",
            "maintainer": "Bitnami <containers@bitnami.com>"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "6f59eae37eba7f2311be05b01709f24210516ce77f3d16ba7df04c22292a400a",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "443/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "443"
                }
            ],
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ],
            "8443/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/6f59eae37eba",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "website_app-network": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "webserver",
                    "e0a6f58269eb"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "ce41a007f03c021c5162a63862f2a520671bfc1a7f1f7917c8ceace25f5a4f25",
                "EndpointID": "5ed5440ba5f089e5308371f106b0a978010d42980f2a876d3e214a2e598b4e20",
                "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.20.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Apache2 configration file on the webserver:etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/website/public
ServerName admin.website.docker

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

[Docker-Compose.yml](https://pastebin.com/8Z6B4AuM)

and finally the `Dockerfile`

[Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/8exuwnw6)

When i entered as sudo and navigated to `/etc/apache2/` folder there where no `sites-enabled` or anything like that just the config file that i copied from my local machine.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a service apache2 reload into your dockerfile after adding the site?

Comment: I have deleted the images multiple times and did a fresh installation on everyting after every change. I messed up a few times the paths. Now everything should be okay. I just don't get where the configuration of the apache is coming from (sites-enabled) and everything else. I want to do a2ensite and a2dissite to fix the configurations but there are not configurations ..

Comment: So I managed to find the `000-default.conf ` after I entered in the docke container with
docker exec -u 0 -it webserver /bin/bash

It's located in `/bin/bash/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

The problem here now is that I have no `VIM`, `NONO`, `GEDIT` or anything else on the server to edit it. I can't use the `docker cp` command to navigate to it from the host machine and `copy/paste` the file to edit it on the machine. I get this response after runing `copy/paste`

`Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/HASH/merged/bin/bash/etc: not a directory`